# jquery .load POST vars

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page where /path (a simple file that echos "test") perfectly:

```
$("#selector").load("/path");
```

but not this (it doesn't load anything):

```
$("#selector").load("/path", {varx:"test"});
```

anyone have any idea?

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is being loaded, then the script is probably returning **no output** when the "varx" request parameter is present. Are you sure you only have:

```
<?php

echo 'hello';

?>
```

?

Comment: shouldn't it load the test page regardless of whether or not a variable is passed?  the /test page is literally a single line that says: echo "test";

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a rewrite rule set on your web server?